# How to get current entryValues from ListPreference in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.record_fragment, container, false);
    ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("formats_listpref");
    CharSequence currText = listPreference.getEntry();
    String currValue = listPreference.getValue();
    return v;
}
```

> The method findPreference(String) is undefined for the type
>   Browse_Fragment

I want to get the currently selected entryValues from ListPreference, I can get the value from Activity but when i use the same code in fragments, its not working `findPreference(String) is undefined` i also tried `getActivity().findPreference` but still it is showing as undefined. thanks in advance .

Comment: which class are you extending ?

Comment: I am extending Fragment class.

Comment: try extending PreferenceFragment instead

Comment: it worked but, when i check the value `System.out.println("listPreference " + listPreference);` it returns null. Do you have any idea ? . I have doubled checked the name it is correct.

Comment: did you call addPreferencesFromResource ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check that your fragment extends PreferenceFragment i.e.

```
public class YourFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
...
}
```

Hope this helps.